# WPF: TreeView unable to apply Hierachical template and style at the same time

Tags: wpf, treeview

Here is what I want to do:

```
<TreeView>
 <TreeView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" >
                    <Setter Property="dz:VirtualListItemBase.AutoLoad" Value="true" />
                </Style>
            </TreeView.Resources>
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Data.Nodes}" >
                    <Label  Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="0"  Content="{Binding Data.Name}" dz:VirtualListItemBase.AutoLoad="true" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

The style part never gets applied. The HierachicalDataTemplate seems to override the initial style. I cannot use the type to apply the template since multiple types are involved. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using ItemContainerStyle member of the ItemTemplate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataTemplate` has higher [precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) over `Style`. Try moving the `DataTemplate` into the `Style` as:

```
 <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" > 
   <Setter Property="dz:VirtualListItemBase.AutoLoad" Value="true" />
   <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
      <Setter.Value>
         <HierarchicalDataTemplate ...
         </HierarchicalDataTemplate> 
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
 </Style>
```

Comment: The style got applied but the hierachicaltemplate did not. Quite bizarre behavior.

Comment: I couldn't recreate it, is it possible to post a non-working sample.